# Can't push to Git repository after merged branch

Tags: git

I'm working on a Git repository, I had my branch (called jviotti) and my changes were merged to Master.
Now, after commiting some changes, I found myself unabled to push to my branch.

```
$ git push origin jviotti
To https://github.com/jorisbontje/pikapay-frontend.git
 ! [rejected]        jviotti -> jviotti (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jorisbontje/pikapay-frontend.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried then git pull:

```
$ git pull
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to rebase against, and 'branch.jviotti.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often rebase against the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:

    [branch "jviotti"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>
    rebase = true

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

After browsing a similar question here at SO, i tried:

```
$ git pull origin master:jviotti
From https://github.com/jorisbontje/pikapay-frontend
 ! [rejected]        master     -> jviotti  (non-fast-forward)
```

I thought that would do the trick. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try ``git pull origin jviotti``?

Comment: When you do `git branch`, what do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first of all make sure your local branch has the upstream branch has its upstream.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to jviotti origin/jviotti
# or
git branch -u jviotti origin/jviotti
```

That is because the new default [push policy will be "simple"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782825/git-config-that-gets-cloned/11783210#11783210).

Once that is done:

```
git pull --rebase origin jviotti
```

That can replay your master history on top of the `origin/jviotti` (as in "[What does it mean when `git pull` causes a conflict but `git pull --rebase` doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874268/what-does-it-mean-when-git-pull-causes-a-conflict-but-git-pull-rebase-doesnt)").

But after that, as in "[`git pull --rebase upstream` & `git push origin` rejects non-fast-forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664919/6309)", you might still need a:

```
git push --force origin jviotti
```

---

The other option is to reset the local repo, as the [OP jviotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641422/jviotti) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783023/cant-push-to-git-repository-after-merged-branch/13783461#comment18954206_13783461):

> I just cloned the repo again, change branch and It worked nice.
>   Awfull git nightmare, everything OK now.

Comment: It sort of looks like he's using local `master` for upstream `jviotti` - is this possible?

Comment: @EricWalker not on the first push:  `jviotti -> jviotti  (non-fast-forward)` means local `jviotti` has diverged. I make sure that local branch has the right upstream one. I agree the `git pull origin master:jviotti`looks shady, but might be inspired by following another SO answer a bit too closely.

Comment: Well I Did git pull --rebase origin jviotti and it worked but It inserted weird chars in my code and broke everything. Then I just cloned the repo again, change branch and It worked nice. Awfull git nightmare, everything OK now. Thanks

Comment: @jviotti: if you ever find yourself in a mess, check out `git reflog`.  You can generally `reset --hard` to any previous commit provided `git gc` has not been run.